# Using Third Party editor in sharepoint 2010

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise

Sharepoint 2010 content editor is better than sharepoint2007 but it's lacking lots of functionality.

Is it possible to "substitute" standard rich text editor with something like Telerik  Rad editor?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

i've no idea which function you care, sharepointboost rich text editor, used for multiple line field type, could achieve the most "text riches" like increase/decrease field area, upload/insert/resize images, insert flash, hyperlinks and so on. don't know if it would help:)

Answer (score 3):

[ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) has sharepoint [support](http://ckeditor.com/sharepoint) as a custom field type. But if you want use it outside field, you can create your own web part (or page) and insert ckeditor there, it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Telerik RadEditor for SharePoint](http://sharepoint.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/Pages/RadEditor-for-SharePoint.aspx). You can download a trial version - to play around with it. Since I have experience with that control, I can tell you that this RTE also has his shortcomings. A perfect RTE does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom field type inheriting *SPFieldMultiLineText* can use any third party RTE as field rendering control.

Normally, the third party RTE controls works with File System context.
For contextual operations like 'upload file', 'add hyperlink of a page' etc , You may need to code a custom SharePoint context provider like Telerik Rad Editor does.